# Is this #14 gauge wire shredded THHN?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Sorry, I didnt know how to add a picture to a reply. Would this fail inspection? I originally purchased a pulling elbow without a cover. Then, per Harper's suggestion, I went out and got a pulling elbow with a cover?

[image: 14 ga]
[image: 2nd picture]

Is there a way in reply to add a picture.

Comment: The black wire looks like thhn but not sure about the other wire type. Thhn has an outer jacket designed to tolerate damage the outer jacket can be badly damaged and would still meet code. The second wire If it is a multi conductor wire and only the outer jacket is damaged that would pass, a photo that is a bit more in focus would be helpful. After looking again the white may be a single wire but the type of insulation is unclear to me from the photo.

Comment: Simply read the text on it. If there is not next on it, it's not. The angle of the picture does not make reading the complete text possible, but it looks like typical wire that has many standards it meets - I can just about make out TWN (or MTW) on the white one, which is often an additional mark on THHN, but really, you should just read it (rather than fuss too much about the picture) and realize that there might be 5 or 6 "type" markings, and that it all repeats every couple of feet.

Comment: @EdBeal Bought from home depot 14ga solid thwn, thhn, or awm or twn75 or t90 nylon gasoline and oil resistant by cerrowire 600 volts with an insul=15mils. Both wires have been replaced with a new open cap 90 degrees pull box elbow.

Comment: So in short, when running 12 or 14 gauge wire, you should never have the covering of the wire have any type of shreds at all when inserting anywhere into and out if the conduit? Where are the guidelines from NEC, so I have a better understanding. Even when i just replace some receptacles, i did find a couple that had some shredding which i did taped or cut off that portion and replace it. Some videos recommended taping the covering--is that acceptable if it is less than an inch or two? To me that seems like a bandage approach? Again thank you all for helping.

Comment: The insulation specifications can be found on the manufacturers web site this is how I found out about the pull jacket some time back.

Comment: Thanks Ed. Learning something everytime I come to the web site.

Answer (score 1):

The wire appears damaged. Regardless of size it would probably fail inspection and should be replaced.

Questions on how to add pictures should be directed to the Meta Stackexchange.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you-- did replace both wires and pull elbow.  NOw have an open cap pull elbow and no shreds. Thank you